# is there a way to authenticate user and password using django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

Is there away to authenticate username and password in Django. all i can find is 
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html

this it is just uses username authentication

Comment: creating sign up page that stores username and password for validating both username and password for login

Comment: You really should check out the Django docs and the pre-built authentication functionality the framework offers.

Comment: i checked the docs the pre-built authentication only uses the username for authentication

Answer (score 0):

Django by default authenticating the user by using of username. If you want to authenticate the user with email instead of username you can check this tutorial.
 
[Authenticate user with email instead of username](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/django-2-register-authenticate-users-email-george-bikas)

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth your while to look at allauth. https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html